# Find the minimal $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that from this $n$ the inequality is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I want to check with induction those inequalities and find the minimal $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that from him the inequality exists

1. $3n-1<2^n$
2. $n^2+1<3^n$
3. $2n^3+1<4^n$

   for (1.) its true only if I take negative numbers and I cant take negative so I cant prove on the first one?

   for (2.) $n=1$? this is the minimal? so I need to prove for $n+1$?

   for (3.) only $n=1$ works.

I want to know if I did things right and would like to get some hints if not.
thanks!

**EDIT**
for (1.) what I did is:
$n=4$ is the minimal number that from him the inequality holds
$n=k>4$ we will get now : $3k-1<2^k$, then I need to check for $k+1$?
so I will get $3(k+1)-1<2^{k+1}$
what now?

Comment: It looks like $n=4$ works for (1.), so you could try proving the statement for all $n\geq4$, 1. holds.

Comment: I am not sure how you come to the conclusions for (1) and (3). I think the answers are (1) 4 (2) 1 (3) 3.

Comment: so I wrong in the way I`m checking the numbers, you can give me an example?

Comment: Do you consider $0$ to be an element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: No, I`m not consider it as element of $\mathbb {N}$

Comment: Ok, I did something wrong in my calculations, I found the numbers as @Tunococ wrote.

Comment: Do you need to find the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the inequality holds for all values greater than or equal to $n$, or the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the inequality holds for $n$?

Comment: Ok, so for the first one the minimal is $4$, now I need to prove for $n+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll help you out with the first one. Hopefully you can do the other two on your own.

You have shown that the base case of $n=4$ works.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that the inequality holds true for $n=k$, where $k\geq4$.

It remains to prove that the inequality holds true for $n=k+1$. Observe that:
$$ \begin{align*}
3(k+1)-1 &= 3k+3-1 \\
&= (3k-1)+3 \\
&< 2^k+3 & \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&< 2^k + 16 \\
&= 2^k + 2^4 \\
&\leq 2^k + 2^k & \text{since } 4 \leq k\\
&= 2(2^k) \\
&= 2^{k+1} \\
\end{align*} $$
as desired. This completes the induction.

Comment: why you choose to move from $3$ to $16$ ?

Comment: Working backwards, I know that I want to eventually end up with $2^{k+1}$, which is the same as $2^k + 2^k$. Somehow, I needed to bound the constant $3$ with $2^k$. To do this, I wanted to use the fact that $k \geq 4$. Hence, since $2^4=16$, I chose to bound it using $16$.

Comment: for the (3.) I tried to implement what you did here and stuck!, what I did is: $$2(k+1)^{3}+1=2k^3+6k^2+6k+2+1<4^{k}+6k^{2}+6k+2$$ what your are suggesting to do?

Comment: Delay applying the induction hypothesis for a bit. Note that if $3 \leq k$, then:
$$ \begin{align*}
2(k+1)^3 + 1
&= 2(k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1) + 1 \\
&< 2(k^3 + 3k^2 + 9k + 27) + 1 \\
&= 2(k^3 + (3)k^2 + (3)^2k + (3)^3) + 1 \\
&\leq 2(k^3 + (k)k^2 + (k)^2k + (k)^3) + 1 \\
&= 2(4k^3) + 1 \\
&= 8k^3 + 1 \\
&< 8k^3 + 4 \\
&= 4(2k^3+1) \\
&< 4(4^k) \\
&= 4^{k+1}
\end{align*} $$